# Can I add shortcuts in Microsoft Word like `=lorem(x)`, `=rand(x)`, etc?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

Can I add shortcuts in Microsoft Word like `=lorem(12)`, `=rand(34)`, etc?  I'm not sure if these are somehow pulling from a stock VBA script (versus something Word-specific) or how to add more.  The [MS KB article about them](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/212251) doesn't go any deeper than just saying what they do.

Comment: The KB seems to now redirect to a short article about how to "Insert a Document in Word", with no mention of the functions.  My guess is that these are simply hard-coded, one-off functions. Useful in certain cases (particularly for the Word developers perhaps), but not much more than an "Easter Egg".

Answer (score 1):

These are Word specific functions (aside from reference in the Word library in VBA from another Office application).

Word VBA does not have access any trappable event for after a user presses return or types a letter (a list of available events as of Word 2003 is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140279%28v=office.10%29.aspx)), so unless there is a way with advanced API calls, it is not possible to create your own.

If you don't need to accept an arguement, you can of course create custom AutoCorrect replacements.